# Ethereum transactions why can't some input data be decoded?

Tags: ethereum

If you look at this transaction https://etherscan.io/tx/0xbc110115f1d9d0d87e25d5d2887261b9f8fb1a3cfb3110723bbec572efd65166 and go down to input data. There is an option to decode the input data, this is common for most transactions. Yet the decode returns nothing. I've seen this several times on Etherscan and BscScan.

I have tried to use https://etherscan.io/bytecode-decompiler but this also does not return anything.

I have read that there is no function which matches on ABI and it looks like the code is used as an internal function for another contract. But how do we decode it? I mean how does the smart chain know how to interpret the code? How can it be viewed as some sort of pseudocode so its transparant what the code is doing?

Comment: Hello, did you find an answer please? same problem here

Comment: @ValentinGarreau The only thing I could find was the contract tab, https://etherscan.io/address/0x24b22b031ae1b5a6b09f9a0fd33613a40e0d70e6#code . It does decode the contract with a few limitations.